# Combining two fixed factors in one factor

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, crossed-random-effects

I have a question about a mixed model I'm running.

The formula is the following:

```
DV ~ Combined * Sex * Arousal + (1 + Combined | Subject) + (1 | Item)
```

My question concerns the factor "Combined". I created it by combining two separate factors plus the common baseline for both factors: Emotion (anger, happiness) and Channel (semantics , prosody, semantics + prosody) + neutral (baseline). The resulting factor is a factor with seven levels: angry prosody, happy prosody, angry semantics, happy semantics, angry prosody + semantics, happy prosody + semantics, neutral.

I have created this combined factor as I'm not interested in the effects of the single factors "emotion" or "channel", but in the interaction of them. Moreover, I tried to run the model with the separate factors

```
DV ~ Emotion * Channel * Sex * Arousal +  (1 + Combined | Subject) + (1 | Item)
```

But I got several problems of convergence. Do you think it is correct to combine the factors in this way?

Comment: I'm confused. You have a factor variable that contain levels like anger and happiness? Are anger and happiness numeric data?

Comment: Maybe the convergence warnings section of the GLMM faq can help you diagnose this: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#convergence-warnings